# Interchanging points on a disc

Tags: general-topology

I've been given an exercise this week which so far I've been unable to prove.

Let C denote the unit circle in the complex plane and D the disc which it bounds. Given a point $x\in D\setminus C$ find a homeomorphism from D to D which interchanges the points x and -x but leaves all the points of C fixed. What if you want to interchange two arbitrary points $x,y \in D\setminus C$ and leave all the points of C fixed?

I've tried to use the map $f(z)=ze^{i \pi  \frac{1-|z|}{1-|x|}}$
Then x and -x are interchanged but I've found it hard to prove that f is bijective, since if we choose $x= \frac{1}{2}$ and consider z=0 as well as z=1 it becomes clear that the function $g(z)=e^{i \pi  \frac{1-|z|}{1-|x|}}$ is not injective. Is there still a way to prove that f is bijective and has a continous inverse?

Answer (score 1):

The map $f$ is bijective because  it is a rotation on each circle $\{z\in D: |z|=r\}$ for $0<r\le 1$ and $f(0)=0$. The inverse function is given by the formula $f^{-1}(z)=ze^{-i \pi  \frac{1-|z|}{1-|x|}}$, so it is continuous. Anyway, any continuous bijection of a compact Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism.